# How to include headers in CMake?

Tags: cmake, include-path

I am having trouble in linking header files to .c files. It will tell me "Cannot open include file: headerfile1.h : No such file directory"

My file structure looks like this

```
library
- folder1
-- include
--- headerfile1.h
--- headerfile2.h
--- CMakeLists.txt
-- CMakeLists.txt
- CMakeLists.txt

src
- file.c
- file.h
- CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists.txt
```

I have read many posts about this and tried a lot. Originally, I tried to create a header-only library or using ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} referencing from a few posts, but was unsuccessful. I would get the same error

Currently, I have this

Under the root CMakeLists.txt, I've added the subdirectories

```
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(library/folder1/include)
```

Under the src CMakeLists.txt, I've included the directory

```
include_directories(library/folder1/include)
```

In file.h, I have

```
#include "include/headerfile2.h"
```

The CMakeLists.txt files I have under the library folder are empty. They were made so that `add_subdirectory(library/folder1/include)` could work

Comment: did you put `include_directories` before `add_subdirectory` commands ? Personnaly i prefer use `target_include_directories` which is more precise, because first command add `-I` options for all the project

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an *interface library* [[1]](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html?highlight=interface%20library#interface-libraries)[[2]](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries) in the `library/folder1/include/CMakeLists.txt` (or the parent one... I dunno what do you have in it and why you need another one in the `include/`).

This library gonna *export* include path via [*build interface*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:BUILD_INTERFACE) (and probably [*install interface*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:INSTALL_INTERFACE) if you plan other projects gonna have this one as an external dependency to be found via `find_package()`).

So, your executable (or whatever) just needs `target_link_library(my_exe PRIVATE my_header_lib)` to get the proper `#include` path.

PS Please, forget about `include_directories()` and use only `target_xxx()` calls.